# Gradient descent problems

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Each time I run the gradient descent for linear regression algorithm, I get three runtime warnings + the cost value is insanely large. I would greatly appreciate all the help :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Data\warsawflatprices.csv.csv", delimiter=",")
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
x_train = data["SizeM2"]
y_train = data["Price"]
m = len(x_train)

def compute_cost(x, y, w, b):
    cost = 0
    for i in range(m):
        cost += (w * x[i] + b - y[i])**2
    cost = cost / (2 * m)
    return cost

def compute_gradient(x, y, w, b):
    dj_dw = 0
    dj_db = 0
    for i in range(m):
        dj_dw += (w * x[i] + b - y[i]) * x[i]
        dj_db += (w * x[i] + b - y[i])
    dj_dw = dj_dw / m
    dj_db = dj_db / m
    return dj_dw, dj_db

def gradient_descent(x, y, w, b, alpha, num_iters):
    cost_history = []
    w_history = []
    b_history = []
    for i in range(num_iters):
        dj_dw, dj_db = compute_gradient(x, y, w, b)
        w = w - alpha * dj_dw
        b = b - alpha * dj_db
        cost = compute_cost(x, y, w, b)
        cost_history.append(cost)
        w_history.append(w)
        b_history.append(b)
    ind = cost_history.index(min(cost_history))
    cost_min = min(cost_history)
    w_min = w_history[ind]
    b_min = b_history[ind]
    print(f"The minimal cost is {cost_min}, the respected parameters are w = {w_min} and b = {b_min}")
gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, 0, 0, 0.01, 10000)
```

```
C:\Users\antho\PycharmProjects\MachineLearningSpecialization\Warsaw Flat Prices (Linear Regression).py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar power
  cost += (w * x[i] + b - y[i])**2
C:\Users\antho\PycharmProjects\MachineLearningSpecialization\Warsaw Flat Prices (Linear Regression).py:21: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar multiply
  dj_dw += (w * x[i] + b - y[i]) * x[i]
C:\Users\antho\PycharmProjects\MachineLearningSpecialization\Warsaw Flat Prices (Linear Regression).py:33: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar subtract
  w = w - alpha * dj_dw
The minimal cost is 365223891369846.8
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for debugging tips. Also look at the `pow()` function to solve the overflow.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not a magic debugging service though. As a minimum, provide your sample data and describe what your code is supposed to do. Especially without your data, it is impossible to reproduce your issue. Additionally, it is generally expected here that you show some minimal effort in identifying the problem yourself to give more targeted advice